# make modal in react native responsive to all devices

Tags: css, ios, react-native, flexbox, styles

trying to create a modal in react native. it works great on iPhone 11 simulator using flex and width & height with percentages.

when checking on iPhone 8 plus and iPads simulator the modal is looking like the attached picture.

[on iPhone 11 simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWt4w.png)

[on iPhone 8 plus simulator (the same as ipad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpmHW.png)

this is the code I used for styling the modal:
cancelConnectRow: {
flex: 0.2,
flexDirection: 'row',
paddingTop: 40,
marginHorizontal: '5%',
marginLeft: 'auto',

```
},
connectButtonText: {
    color: '#08A7CC',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontFamily: '.././assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf',
},
cancelButtonText: {
    color: '#282F39',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontFamily: '.././assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf',
    marginRight: 20
},
checkboxLine: {
    flex: 0.7,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
checboxStyle:{
},
showPasswordText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontFamily: '.././assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf',
},
topHeadlinePopup: {
    flex: 1,
    fontFamily: '.././assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf', 
    fontSize: 22, 
},
secondHeadlinePopup: {
    fontFamily: '.././assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf', 
    fontSize: 16, 
    lineHeight: 50, 
    opacity: 0.5,
},
modalStyle: {
    opacity: 0.5,
    backgroundColor:"#282F39",
},
innerModalStyle: {
    backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF", 
    margin: 50, 
    padding: 30, 
    flex: 1, 
    marginTop: '75%', 
    marginBottom: '75%',
    opacity: 1,
},
inputFieldPopup: {
    width: '100%', 
    borderBottomColor: '#BBBBBB', 
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 2
},
popupContainer: {
    flex: 1,

},
popupTextInput: {
    flex: 0.15,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so i figured it out. i used dimensions to get the height like this:

import Dimensions from 'react-native';

```
useEffect(() => {
    const onChange = () => {
        setScreenData(Dimensions.get('window').height);
        };
        Dimensions.addEventListener('change', onChange);

        return () => {Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', onChange)};
    });
```

and then used the variable screenData to change the height of the Modal according to the screen size with percentages like this:
<View style={{ marginVertical: screenData * 0.32 }}>